# java - javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, file, encryption, memory-management, aes

I am `reading` a `large file` in small-small `bytes` `chunks`. I am `encrypting` that file, chunk by chunk, using `AES 128 bit encryption` and `writing` each encrypted chunk into another file.  The File is `Encrypted` `successfully`.

But when I am `reading` that `encrypted` file back in small-small `bytes` `chunks` and trying to `decrypt` that file- chunk by chunk, it throws an Exception

```
java - javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

But when I am trying to read the whole file and try to `decrypt` bytes, it `decryptes` successfully.

Here is my code:

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 * Created by Ashish Pancholi on 22-12-2016.
 */
public class EncryDecryPtion implements Securable{
    public static void main(String[] argu){
        EncryDecryPtion encryDecryPtion = new EncryDecryPtion();
        File file = new File("shouldbeoriginal.jpg");
        try {
            encryDecryPtion.encryptFile(file,"Pa$$w0rd");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        File file_ = new File("shouldbeoriginal.jpg");
        try {
            encryDecryPtion.decryptFile(file_,"Pa$$w0rd");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 




import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

/**
 * Encrypt and decrypt file with AES algorithm
 * Created by Ashish Pancholi on 20-12-2016.
 */
public interface Securable {

    /**
     * Read and write the file in chunk.
     * Encrypts the chunks with AES algorithm.
     * It creates a new a file which having encrypted data,
     * deletes old original file and
     * rename a new file with the old file
     * @param file which is to be encrypted and password.
     */

    default File encryptFile(File file, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
        String encryptedFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".ENCRYPTED";
        File encryptedFile = new File(encryptedFilePath);
        encryptedFile.createNewFile();
        try
                (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            try
                    (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile)) {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                int chunkLen = 0;
                while ((chunkLen = in.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                    byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.encrypt(chunk);
                    out.write(encryptedChunk);
                }
            }
        }
        Path path_originalFile = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Path path_encryptedFile = Paths.get(encryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.delete(path_originalFile);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            try {
                FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
            }catch (IOException ex1){
                //ignore
            }
        }
        Path path = Files.move(path_encryptedFile, path_originalFile);
        return path.toFile();
    }

    default File encryptWholeFile(File file, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
        String encryptedFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".ENCRYPTED";
        File encryptedFile = new File(encryptedFilePath);
        encryptedFile.createNewFile();
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
            byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.encrypt(bytes);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(encryptedFile, encryptedChunk);
        }
        Path path_originalFile = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Path path_encryptedFile = Paths.get(encryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.delete(path_originalFile);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            try {
                FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
            }catch (IOException ex1){
                //ignore
            }
        }
        Path path = Files.move(path_encryptedFile, path_originalFile);
        return path.toFile();
    }

    /**
     * Read and write the file in chunk.
     * Encrypts the chunks with AES algorithm.
     * It creates a new a file which having encrypted data,
     * deletes old original file and
     * rename a new file with the old file
     * @param inputStream of file which is to be encrypted and a password.
     */
    default InputStream encryptFile(InputStream inputStream, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        InputStream in;
        try {
            AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                int chunkLen = 0;
                while ((chunkLen = inputStream.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                    byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.encrypt(chunk);
                    baos.write(encryptedChunk);
                }
                baos.flush();
                in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            }
        }finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return in;
    }

    /**
     * Read and write the file in chunk.
     * Encrypts the chunks with AES algorithm.
     * It creates a new a file which having encrypted data,
     * deletes old original file and
     * rename a new file with the old file
     * @param inputStream of file which is to be encrypted and a password.
     */
    default File encryptFile(InputStream inputStream, String password, String targetFileName) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        File encryptedFile = new File(targetFileName);
        try {
            AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
            encryptedFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            encryptedFile.createNewFile();
            try (OutputStream baos = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile)) {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                int chunkLen = 0;
                while ((chunkLen = inputStream.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                    byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.encrypt(chunk);
                    baos.write(encryptedChunk);
                }
            }
        }finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        return encryptedFile;

    }

    /**
     * Read and write the file in chunk.
     * Decrypts the chunks with AES algorithm.
     * It creates a new a file which having decrypted data,
     * deletes old original encrypted file and
     * rename a new file with the old file
     * @param file which is to be decrypted and password.
     */

    default void decryptFile(File file, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
        String decryptedFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".DECRYPTED";
        File decryptedFile = new File(decryptedFilePath);
        decryptedFile.createNewFile();
        try
                (FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            try
                    (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(decryptedFile)) {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                int chunkLen = 0;
                while ((chunkLen = in.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                    byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.decrypt(chunk);
                    out.write(encryptedChunk);
                }
            }
        }
        Path path_originalFile = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Path path_decryptedFile = Paths.get(decryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.delete(path_originalFile);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            try {
                FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
            }catch (IOException ex1){
                //ignore
            }
        }
        Files.move(path_decryptedFile, path_originalFile);
    }

    default File decryptWholeFile(File file, String password) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException {
        AESEncryptionDecryption aesEncryptionDecryption = new AESEncryptionDecryption(password);
        String decryptedFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath() + ".DECRYPTED";
        File decryptedFile = new File(decryptedFilePath);
        decryptedFile.createNewFile();
        try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
                byte[] encryptedChunk = aesEncryptionDecryption.decrypt(bytes);
                FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(decryptedFile, encryptedChunk);
          }
        Path path_originalFile = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Path path_decryptedFile = Paths.get(decryptedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        try {
            Files.delete(path_originalFile);
        }catch (IOException ex){
            try {
                FileUtils.forceDelete(file);
            }catch (IOException ex1){
                //ignore
            }
        }
       Path path =  Files.move(path_decryptedFile, path_originalFile);
        return path.toFile();
    }

}


import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


/**
 * Encrypt and decrypt file with AES algorithm
 * Created by Ashish Pancholi on 20-12-2016.
 */

public class AESEncryptionDecryption {

    private SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private byte[] key;

    public AESEncryptionDecryption(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException{
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        key = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); // use only first 128 bit
        this.secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the file with AES algorithm
     * @param bytes of file which is to encrypted
     * @return byte[] which is encrypted bytes
     */
    public byte[] encrypt(byte[] bytes) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
            byte[] encrytedBytes = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
            return encrytedBytes;

    }

    /**
     * Decrypts the file with AES algorithm
     * @param encrytedBytes of file that to be decrypted
     * @return byte[] which is original data.
     */
    public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encrytedBytes) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(encrytedBytes);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

SO my Question is- **How to encrypt a large file without loading the whole file in the memory?** Please help.

**EDITED**

Here is the updated code but still I am getting the same exception on line `cipher.doFinal()` when decrypting:

```
public void encrypt(File sourceFile, File targetFile) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
    try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile)){
        try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)){
            byte[] chunk = new byte[8192];
            int chunkLen = 0;
            while ((chunkLen = inputStream.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                byte[] encrytedBytes = cipher.update(chunk);
                outputStream.write(encrytedBytes);
            }
            byte[] finalBytes =  cipher.doFinal();
            if(finalBytes!=null) {
                outputStream.write(finalBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void decrypt(File encryptedFile, File targetFile) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, IOException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, this.secretKey);
    try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(encryptedFile)){
        try(OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)){
            byte[] chunk = new byte[8192];
            int chunkLen = 0;
            while ((chunkLen = inputStream.read(chunk)) != -1) {
                byte[] decrytedBytes = cipher.update(chunk);
                outputStream.write(decrytedBytes);
            }
            byte[] finalBytes =  cipher.doFinal();
            if(finalBytes!=null) {
                outputStream.write(finalBytes);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the random capital P in the middle of the word?

Comment: I agree that's the wrong way of naming classes. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `cipher.update(...)` methods when you stream through the file, and only use the `cipher.doFinal(...)` as the last call. The `doFinal` flushes the buffers + do padding etc, that you don't want to do more than one time.

If you do a `doFinal(...)` in your decrypt prematurely, it will (very likely) fail as a correct padding is missing in the data.

Edit:

Don't use ECB mode it's insecure. Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) and scroll down to the penguin.

Don't generate your keys by a simple Sha-1 - use a proper key deriviation function like [PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256-bit-aes-password-based-encryption/992413#992413).

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Thank you very much. But still, I am  not able to decrypt the file. Actually while decrypting the file, I followed the same way that you suggested in your answer, I used `cipher.update(...)` when I stream through a file but when I used `cipher.doFinal(...)` as the last call, it throwing an Exception again- `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded`.

Comment: One strange thing is also happening here - In `decryption`, when I commented out the `cipher.doFinal(...)` from code then file decrypted successfully (only, by using  `cipher.update(...)`) . So do we not need to use `doFinal(...)` while `decrypting`? I wonder if that really encrypted. Is that very easy to decrypt the file by hackers?

Comment: Basically `cipher.update(...)` would not fail on decrypt, even with random input as it don't inspect the data it decrypt. If you omit the `doFinal(...)` you will end up missing the last block of data as this will be stuck in a buffer to allow for proper padding. How big is your encrypted data compared to the data in clear?  It should be 1 to 16 bytes bigger than the input (padded to nearest multiple of 16).

Comment: No change in size. BTW.. I have updated the question by adding two methods  at the end in which I am doing exactly what you have suggested. Please look into these method and let me know if I am doing something wrong. Unfortunately I am still getting the same Exception when calling `doFinal(...)` at the time of `decryption`. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You encrypt the full buffer with `cipher.update(chunk)`, even when chunkLen is less than 8192 .. you need to tell how much of the data in the buffer you want encrypted when data is less than 8192 ..

Comment: Like `byte[] encrytedBytes = cipher.update(chunk, 0, chunkLen);` .. same goes for decrypt ..

Answer (score 1):

Initially I was using `cipher.doFinal()` for both Encryption and Decryption modes. Runtime Exceution was fine but testcases were failing with `BadPaddingException()`. Then I changed the code to

```
byte[] output = this.cipher.update(input, 0, input.length);
```

And now the decryption is working fine. Same goes for Encryption as well.

Comment: This did the trick for me. Thanks a lot!!